How to play .avi videos stored on S3 in a web application (Node.js + React)?
I have a web application built with Node.js and React. Users upload videos in the .avi format to an AWS S3 bucket. I need to play these .avi videos on the web application, but .avi format is not natively supported by most web browsers. I’m looking for the best approach to implement this functionality effectively.
I tried directly embedding the .avi videos in the React application using HTML5 video tags and various video player libraries like react-player. However, the videos do not play because the .avi format is not supported by web browsers. I expected to find a solution or workaround to either play .avi videos directly or convert them to a web-friendly format dynamically.
Thanks in advance.

You need to provide a testable .avi  link in order to get advice about playing it.

I didn't find a way to render ".avi" videos from the S3.
As alternative, I changed the video producer to produce ".mp4", a video format that is supported by the browser.
